# Google Calendar trigger when an event occurs

Tags: web-applications, synchronization, google-calendar-api

I'm building a web app which integrates with Google Calendar's new API through OAuth2 and I was wondering if there is any way of "subscribing" to events and be notified, something like a callback, when they occur.

I don't see any hint for this in their official documentation but I thought I might try it: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

The main problem is that if you want to do both way sync between your app and GC you'd need to continuously query the GC API for changes. If the number of integrations in the same system goes up, the total time between complete sync cycles also increases a lot.

Also, if someone knows other web apps which integrate nicely with GC and innovate with their implementation, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any way of subscribing to google calendars triggers at them moment (although I agree, this would be very useful). You can only do this with spreadsheets, docs and forms that are saved on google drive.

According to Google dev documentation:

> "They are applicable to scripts bound to spreadsheets, documents, or forms."
>
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events